# Unload images from MySQL to disk

Tags: mysql, sql, into-outfile

I have images stored in MySQL as blobs (*i know it's wrong*). And there are many of them. Is there any fast way to drop them all on disk, like `SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE`, but to many files insted of one? Or the only way is writing a script that will iterate over rows and save images?

Comment: Just out of interest, why is it wrong? [I have always steered clear of using Blobs for Image data as well, but I don't have a good reason for doing so ! (Apart from the fact that image-data is more 'hidden' from diagnostics / debugging).

Comment: It's slow like molasses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want them to be saved into different files on the disk you'll have to go for a script.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#Note: it is my habit to name a Query Result $qR.

use strict;
use DBI;
my $dbh = DBI->connect(YOUR_INFO_HERE);

my $i = 0;
my $q = $dbh->prepare('select image from images');
while (my $qR = $q->fetchrow_arrayref) {
    open(FILE,'>',"$i.jpg");
    print FILE $qR[0];
    close FILE;
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement , I found in my case using Java + Hibernate (possibly similar task in other Hibernate variations, but not tried it), got me there quite quickly.

I set up a mapping like this:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="<com.package.table>" table="table">
    <id column="pk" name="pk" type="int">
    </id>
    <property name="blobfield" type="blob"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

A Java bean to carry the data, something like:

```
package com.package;
import java.sql.Blob;
...
public class table {
...
public Blob getBlobfield {
...
```

And a loop something like this:

```
 ...
 tx = session.beginTransaction();
 Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(table.class);
 crit.setMaxResults(50); // Alter this to suit...
           List<table> rows = crit.list();
           for (table r: rows) {
               ExtractBlob(r.getId(), r.getBlobField);
 }
```

And something ("ExtractBlob" is I'm calling this) to extract the blob (using the PK to generate a filename), something like this:

...

```
 FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(<...base output file on PK for example...>
 BufferedOutputStream bos=new BufferedOutputStream(fout);
 InputStream is=blob.getBinaryStream();
 byte[] b=new byte[8192];
 while ( (is.read(b))>0 ) {
       bos.write(b);
 }
 is.close();
 bos.close()
```

;

...

I can post a more complete example if you looks like it might be useful - but I would have extract the code from a bigger project, otherwise I would have just posted it straight up.

Comment: Sadly, I don't know Java. But I'm pretty sure I can do it in PHP :)